# Как поменять имя проекта в AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio

Как поменять имя проекта в AndroidStudio, чтобы все корректно прописалось внутри.

Answer (score 1):

1. Выберите проект (если список)
2. нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
3. Пишем новое название проекта, ОК